# DVD-R vs DVD+R for liveCD

Tags: live-cd, livedvd

for the past year and a half or so, I have been using Ubuntu as a secondary OS, running it off of a portable HDD.  Within the past 2 weeks, my portable HDD has started to show worrying signs of imminent disk-death.  I have a replacement drive, but i need to copy over the entirety of the first HDD to the second.  In order to get access to the tools I would need (`dd` will make a 100% complete bit-for-bit copy of a multi-partition drive to a new drive, correct?), I'm going to have to run a liveCD of linux.

I've been trying to figure out if I should be using a DVD-R or a DVD+R for the liveCD.  Is there any noticeable difference as far as a ubuntu liveCD goes, between the two standards?

Answer (score 1):

Use a DVD -R , less expensive, and there is no real need for +R

Even better, get a 2 Gb flash drive, much cheaper in the long run then DVD.

Comment: what's the actual difference?  and the flash drive is possible, but i think i'll need a second liveCD for gparted, in order to resize some partitions once i get the second physical drive identical to the original.  i'm going to thrown maybe kali linux in there as well, see if i can get it to work.